# HTTP status code returned by Apache configured as proxy with proxytimeout directive

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, proxy, python, http

I have a general question about the behavior of Apache webserver which is configured as a proxy server and has a directive *ProxyTimeout* set at 1 second for testing purpose.

My backend (upsteam) server is a Python built-in HTTP Server which deliberately waits for longer then 1 second to send the response to the proxy server (abovementioned Apache), and sends it 3 seconds after it received the request.

According to the official Apache docs(https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout)

the proxy should wait for response from backend server for amount of time specified in *ProxyTimeout* directive and if there's no response it must "return a timeout" which is, as far as I understand, a status code 504, because the specification of this status code says:
*504 Gateway Timeout - The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a timely response from the upstream server*.

Nevertheless, when I send requests to the proxy server, it returns error code 502, which indicates that the proxy receives invalid response from the upstream server.

So I try to understand why this happens. Why the status code is 502 instead of 504 when the upstream server it ok, it just can't respond to the server because of expired timeout?

The error logs of Apache correctly inform:

`[proxy_http:error] [pid 6040] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 192.168.56.1:53331] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 127.0.0.1:8080"`

The upstream backend server throws BrokenPipeError which I catch in an exception and does not let it crash, so to my knowledge it should not be a server's fault, but rather the expected behavior because the connection is closed after 1 second and there's nowhere to send it.

Maybe someone can help me understand what could be the cause of this behavior and why *ProxyTimeout* does not make Apache return 504 which is logical according to the documentation?

Thanks in advance!